# Max int in list ocaml

Tags: ocaml

I want to find the max element in a int list.
The idea is to call `find_max` only once and let `support` do the dirty job.
The function `support` returns an int, the first value is 0 then when a new `max` is found it's value is saved, added to the result ,the previous max is changed and it's value deducted from the result.

This because :

```
old_max = x
result = 0 + old_max
```

A new max is found :

```
new_max= y
result = result - oldmax + new_max
```

So I'll save the value of `new_max` :

```
0 + old_max - old_max + new_max = new_max`.
```

Obviously the code above is explicative, this is my real code :

```
let find_max random  = 
  let rec support rlist max =
    if rlist==[] then 0
    else 
      if (List.hd rlist) > max 
      then -max + (List.hd rlist) + support (List.tl rlist) (List.hd rlist)
      else support (List.tl rlist) max ;;
  let return = support random 0 0 ;
  !return;;

let a = [1;2;3];
print_string "max element in list is : "
print_int (find_max a);
print_string "\n"
```

The error is on line 9 `!return;;`, syntax error (obviously :/ ) on `;;`

Comment: Hey, you have now asked three questions (the other ones are https://stackoverflow.com/q/62484643/20371 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/62497947/20371 ) where the answer is the same: not using the `let ... in ...` syntax properly. This was explained quite well in an answer to your first question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62488711/20371 . I think you had better go and read that carefully to internalize it, and familiarize yourself with the basic syntax rules.

Comment: Hi @Yawar, yes I know I was a little stressful, sorry about that. But now I understood (more or less ) how to use "let...in". Ocaml's official doc isn't quite good I read it from here : ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/basics.html but I learn a lots of stuffs these days. Take a look to my latest question, and you'll see that I'm going better ( I hope ) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62531154/handle-recursive-function-within-an-other-function-ocaml . I need of  1-2 stuffs more and I got it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no construct `let ... = ...;` in OCaml, local definition use `let .. = ... in ...` . You probably want to avoid using `;;` altogether as a beginner too.

Also, structural equality is `=` and not `==`. Similarly, you should *never* use`List.hd` and `List.tl` in your code as a beginner. Pattern matching is always the superior option.
Typically, all uses of those functions can be replaced by a simple:

```
match rlist with
| [] -> 0
| hd :: tl -> ...
```

which is shorter, clearer, and eliminate any possibility to mishandle the empty list.
Your logic is also unnecessarily complex rather than computing `max - initial_value` with

```
-max + hd + support tl hd
```

you can compute the maximum directly with

```
hd
```

You are then calling support `support` with too many argument.
We may want to use `let () = ...`  when computing effect, rather than using `;;`.

Comment: I have some troubles with 'match' and its cases...This kind of programming is a bit hard for me...I prefer C,C++,Java...This is weird for me...Do you know where I can read and know more to understand mechanics behind this kind of programming language? For me is hard to focus on the mechanics...

Comment: I think you see that I'm coding like C,Java...I still don't get the functional programming style but I want to.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this is an excellent place to use `List.fold_left` and the standard library's `max` function. No mutable state to worry about and it's tail-recursive.

```
let find_max lst =
  List.fold_left max 0 lst
```

To understand how this works, take a look at how a left fold is implemented.

```
let rec fold_left f init lst =
  match lst with
  | [] -> init
  | x::xs -> fold_left f (f init x) xs
```

If we evaluate `find_max []` we get `List.fold_left max 0 []` which simply evaluates to `0` as documented in your original question.

If we evaluate `find_max [1; 3; 2; 4; 5; 0]` then we'd see a progression like:

```
find_max [1; 3; 2; 4; 5; 0]
List.fold_left max 0 [1; 3; 2; 4; 5; 0]
List.fold_left max (max 0 1) [3; 2; 4; 5; 0]
List.fold_left max (max 1 3) [2; 4; 5; 0]
List.fold_left max (max 3 2) [4; 5; 0]
List.fold_left max (max 3 4) [5; 0]
List.fold_left max (max 4 5) [0]
List.fold_left max (max 5 0) []
5
```